# Which editors color/highlight between the $...$ with syntax coloring?

Tags: math-mode, editors, highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

I'd like to know which TeX editors have syntax coloring options which color/highlight the math mode text between the $...$. This way it is easy to see when you are missing a $.

Currently, I am using TeXShop, but despite some discussion in Nov 2002 on MacOSTex, this feature seems to have never been added.

Hence, I'd like a list of editors with this feature.  (I am interested in Mac OS, but it may be useful to have a more general list.)  This is a difficult thing to search for on Google without just trying each editor and looking at it's syntax coloring.

**UPDATE: Per doncherry's comments below, please add this information to the big list of [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).**

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It'll probably be better to add this information to our big list of editors that we already have: [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339)

Comment: [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) does but I don't know if it is available for Mac.

Comment: Have you tried TextMate? At least it makes the whole $...$ part green in my current theme. But it's very customizable.

Comment: The TeX modes of Emacs fontify the text inside $-pairs, too.

Comment: @doncherry The "big list" didn't have the information I was looking for.  (Just knowing an editor has syntax highlighting, doesn't mean it colors everything between the $'s.  For example, TexShop.)  But as far as my original question, the TexMaker answer below was satisfactory for my needs.

Comment: @JasonRute: Yes, the idea was that this information would be added to each entry in the big list. You could add something to the question asking users to add this information to the answers whenever they know it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using TexMaker which has syntax highlighting. It's free and both Windows and Linux friendly.

Comment: It is also Mac-friendly.

Comment: Assuming the answer satisfied you, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.